# Can you say "the events of yesterday?"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, phrases

While reading through my writing, I noticed that I wrote: "During the events of yesterday..." because it fit the narrative. The phrase, however, made me wonder whether it's correct. When I googled the words "the events of yesterday", all I found was an article dating back to the 1860s, in New York Times that used this exact phrase. The modern term seems to just be: "During yesterday's events".

My question is then, as asked in the title, while perhaps a bit old-fashioned, is it still grammatically correct in modern English to use the words: "During **the events of yesterday**"? – or has it completely fallen out of use?

Comment: during yesterday's events = much more common. If you want to write in English, you need to pay attention to possessives. They can get complicated.

Comment: If Google NGrams is to be believed, the Saxon genitive version ***today's events*** became more popular than ***events of today*** [over 50 years ago.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=today%27s+events%2Cevents+of+today&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctoday%20%27s%20events%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevents%20of%20today%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctoday%20's%20events%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevents%20of%20today%3B%2Cc0) But "**completely fallen out of use**"? That's a bit extreme!

Comment: You will frequently see "events of..." used with a date: "The events of January sixth." But if the day is described by a single word, then the possessive is much more idiomatic: "Yesterday's events" or "Sunday's events."

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a wee bit unclear since the title doesn't mention "during, whereas the body does. And Ngram suggests that it's the "During" that's minimizing the number of results, because "the events of yesterday" itself (i.e. no "during") gets lots of hits, many of them recent.

So if you include "during", then "the events of yesterday" may not be common, but as @FumbleFingers commented, it's too much to say that it has completely fallen out of use. And if you exclude "during" then it's still common. Either way, I don't see any problem in using it.

And I just thought of a situation where even with "During", you may *have* to use "the events of yesterday" rather than "yesterday's events". Suppose there was some terrorist attack at the Olympics. A report about that may need to use "events" to refer to both the actual sporting activities, but also to the terrorist attack. To make the distinction, you'd pretty much have to use "the events of yesterday" to refer to the attack, because "yesterday's events" would likely be take to refer to the sporting activities.

Is my example contrived? Very well then, it is contrived, (I am large, I contain multitudes.)